# podman rootless virtual subnet with containers externally accessible by IP, is this possible?

Tags: networking, podman

### Goal

- Setup a virtual network in which multiple containers are started
- each container should be accessible by its IP from the host network
- the containers run rootless (it is intended to run the test network from a CI runner)
- it is acceptable to run a specific `iptables` command with `sudo` which allows the necessary forwards to the virtual network

The reason I'm avoiding using published ports is that I want the virtual network to resemble "reality" in which a larger number of services will be running on separate hardware, and the fact that they'll be using different IPs matters to the coordination service.

### My approach

```
$ podman network create --subnet 10.10.10.0/24 virtnet1
$ ( export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=; podman run --rm -d --name nmt --network virtnet1 praqma/network-multitool )
```

(The `DBUS` hack is a workaround for [this issue](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=253966))

If I now look at `iptables -L` I see the chains `CNI-FORWARD`, and I was naively assuming that a simple

```
sudo iptables -A CNI-FORWARD -d 10.10.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

to be able to access the containers from the host network. But they still appear strictly separated and inaccessible. (The `FORWARD` chain has `ACCEPT` policy by default, so no problem there.)

Is it fundamentally impossible (I haven't found any examples of this), or am I just doing something wrong?

Might the `CNI-*` chains be related to any previous rootful containers, since logically rootless wouldn't be able to affect anything `iptables` related anyway?

Comment: Were you find solution for this? I have similar problem

Comment: @NehaDalal no, I'm still getting by with one IP and a large number of different ports, which are automatically defined in an ansible script that instantiates the services. The IP is just the one of the host running the containers, and the containers expose the (generated) port numbers.